# Lose setting when redeploy tomcat app?

Tags: java, tomcat, settings, redeploy

When you redeploy a tomcat application, does it lose previous settings/files? Is the war completely overwritten?  Or does it keep the unchanged files, and just overwrite the changed ones?

Thanks,
MirroredFate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy a war on your tomcat server it will delete all the files and then add it.

Comment: @jared im sorry im not 100% sure. ill try to look into it and let u know